# i want to delete a guest status node in guests in firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

In my database, I have a guest status that I want to delete when the check-in button is clicked but it not deleting. This is my shareViewModel:

```
class ShareViewModel: ViewModel() {
    var firstName : MutableState<String?> = mutableStateOf(null)

    private val _selectedGuest = MutableLiveData<Guest>()
    val selectedGuest: LiveData<Guest> get() = _selectedGuest

    fun setSelectedGuest(guest: Guest) {
        _selectedGuest.value = guest
    }

    // Function to update the status in Firebase
    fun updateGuestStatus(status: String) {
        val currentGuest = _selectedGuest.value
        currentGuest?.let {
            it.status = status
            updateStatusInFirebase(it)
            _selectedGuest.value = it
        }
    }

    // Function to delete the guest's status in Firebase
    fun deleteGuestStatus() {
        val currentGuest = _selectedGuest.value
        currentGuest?.let {
            it.status = ""// Set status to null to indicate deletion
            Log.d("DeleteGuestStatus", "Deleting status for guest: ${it.id}")
            updateStatusInFirebase(it)
            _selectedGuest.value = it
        }
    }

    // Function to get the guest's current status
    fun getGuestStatus(): String? {
        return _selectedGuest.value?.status
    }

    private fun updateStatusInFirebase(guest: Guest) {
        val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        val userUid = user?.uid

        if (userUid != null) {
            val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            val guestsRef = database.getReference("users/$userUid/guests")

            // Assuming that 'guest.id' contains the unique identifier of the guest
            val guestId = guest.id

            // Use setValue(null) to remove the "status" field
            guestsRef.child(guestId).child("status").setValue(null)
        }
    }
}
```

and my SecurityScreen where i want check in button to delete the guest staus in my firebase

```
@Composable
fun SecurityScreen(navController: NavController, shareViewModel: ShareViewModel) {

    var guests by remember {
        mutableStateOf<List<Guest>>(emptyList())
    }
    var selectedGuest by remember { mutableStateOf<Guest?>(null) }
    val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    val usersRef = database.getReference("users")

    LaunchedEffect(usersRef) {
        // Add a listener for all users
        usersRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                val allGuests = mutableListOf<Guest>()

                // Iterate through each user's guests
                for (userSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                    val guestsSnapshot = userSnapshot.child("guests")
                    for (guestSnapshot in guestsSnapshot.children) {
                        val guest = guestSnapshot.getValue(Guest::class.java)
                        guest?.let { allGuests.add(it) }
                    }
                }

                // Update the guest list
                guests = allGuests
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                // Handle any errors here if needed
            }
        })
    }

    fun deleteGuestStatus(guest: Guest) {
        shareViewModel.setSelectedGuest(guest)
        shareViewModel.deleteGuestStatus()
    }



    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
        Text(
            text = "Security Department",
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(bottom = 16.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            fontSize = 20.sp,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        )

        LazyColumn(
            content = {
                items(
                    items = guests.chunked(4), // Group guests into pairs (2 per row)
                    itemContent = { rowItems ->
                        Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly) {
                            rowItems.forEach { guest ->
                                GridItem(
                                    guest = guest,
                                    onClick = { selectedGuest = guest },
                                    onCheckInClick =  { deleteGuestStatus(guest) }
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        )
        // Display a dialog when a guest card is clicked
        selectedGuest?.let { guest ->
            Dialog(
                onDismissRequest = { selectedGuest = null },
                properties = DialogProperties(
                    dismissOnBackPress = true,
                    dismissOnClickOutside = true
                )
            ) {

                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(16.dp)
                        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
                        .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background)
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = "Name: ${guest.name}",
                        fontSize = 18.sp,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
                    )
                    Text(
                        text = "Contact: ${guest.phoneNumber}",
                        fontSize = 18.sp,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(
                            start = 8.dp,
                            end = 8.dp,
                            bottom = 16.dp
                        )
                    )
                    Row(
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                        modifier = Modifier,
                    ) {
                        TextButton(onClick = {
                            // Update the status to "In" when Check In is clicked
                            deleteGuestStatus(guest)
                        }) {
                            Text(text = "Check In",
                                fontSize = 20.sp,
                                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,)
                        }
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
                        TextButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                            Text(text = "Check Out",
                                fontSize = 20.sp,
                                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,)
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun GridItem(guest: Guest, onClick: () -> Unit, onCheckInClick: () -> Unit) {

    Card(
        shape = CircleShape,
        colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
            containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
        ),
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(75.dp)
            .padding(8.dp)
            .clickable(onClick = onClick)
    ) {
        Text(
            text = guest.randomNumbers.joinToString(","),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .wrapContentSize(Alignment.Center),
            fontSize = 18.sp,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary
        )
    }
}
```

I expected the status in my database to delete when the check in button is clicked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When using the following line of code:

```
it.status = ""// Set status to null to indicate deletion
```

You aren't deleting the status but assigning an empty string. An empty string is different than `null`. To delete a node in the Realtime Database you can assign `null`:

```
it.status = null // Set status to null to indicate deletion
//
```

Or you can call [removeValue()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#removeValue()) on a [DatabaseReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference) object. If you do that, don't forget to attach a listener to the remove value operation, so you can see if something goes wrong.

Comment: thank you for your response but the status is still not deleting even when i have set var Status : String? = null and it.status = null.  i would appreciate if i can get a function to change the current guest status  which is "Booked" as appear in my firebase database to "in" when the function is call. thanks

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the remove value operation? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: yes but no error message

Comment: Is onComplete even triggered?

Comment: what is oncomplete

Comment: When you attach a complete listener, you need to provide an implementation for `onComplete`. Is this method even triggered?

Comment: Hey Dox. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?